# Intellij 12 Ultimate is having problems with international characters

Tags: internationalization, intellij-idea

I have multiple problems with Intellij 12 on my Mac.

1. If I create a project with in a directroy containg norwegian characters, the IDE is not able to find the project directory and will not even start the compile process
2. If I have a Java Class with an international character, the compiler throws this out

   13.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Fårekjøtt
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: F��rekj��tt
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)

   Process finished with exit code 1

What is the correct way to go about fixing this?

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but the safest approach is not to use java classes with international characters in them.

Comment: Well, so much for Domain Drives design then :)

Comment: @vikingsteve I guess this is a typical example of how it is valuable to follow a problem to the end, in stead of just giving up and taking the shortcut. I really want the Java Classes to be in the domain language. Now I can do that.

Comment: Nice one! Glad u figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac SDK 1.7_40 has a fix for a known bug causing this problem. If you add the Oracle SDK 1.7_40 to IDEA, it compiles.

From Jetbrains support;

> You are trying to compile with Oracle JDK 1.7 on Mac which has known
>   problems with encoding on this system. Please use the default Apple
>   JDK to avoid this problem or convert your files to UTF-8. I've
>   verified that compilation with Apple JDK 1.6 works without problems:
>   https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rga4d0zphksvvd/Screenshot%202013-10-04%2020.20.44.png
>   . Don't forget to remove the invalid -encoding option that you have
>   added to Preferences | Compiler. If using JDK 1.6 is not an option,
>   you can also try JDK 1.7.0_40 version from Oracle which may (or may
>   not) have a fix for this problem.